# How to replace occurences in string using groups in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I simply need to replace:

`<p>`, `<div>`

with

`\n<p>`, `\n<div>`

in string with one single pattern replacing. Is it possible?

```
let string = "<p>hello</p> my <div>Doggy</div>"
let newString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "<p>", with: "\n<p>").replacingOccurrences(of: "<div>", with: "\n<div>")
```

is there a better solution with regex?

Comment: that seems to me a static _seek-and-replace_ procedure of 2 values – why would you think you may need a reg-exp for a _better solution_ (whatever that actually means in this context)?

Comment: I need to replace the following tags: `p, div, ul, li, h1, h2` with `\n{tag}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a regular expression search, with a template in the replacement
string:

```
let string = "<p>hello</p> my <div>Doggy</div>"
let newString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "<p>|<div>", with: "\n$0", options: .regularExpression)
```

For each match, the `$0` template is replaced by what actually matched the pattern.

Comment: As always, you are genius;)