# How to insert a substring before/after another substring?

Tags: swift, string

Let's say we have the string `"asd as asdsd"`, I need to insert `"<*>"` before and after `"asd"`, so the result should be: `"<*>asd<*> as <*>asd<*>sd"`.

The insertion should be caseInsensitive, so if the target is `"ASD"` the result is the same:  `"<*>asd<*> as <*>asd<*>sd"`

I tried

```
a.insert(contentsOf: separator, at: a.range(of: "asd", options: .caseInsensitive)!.upperBound)
a.insert(contentsOf: separator, at: a.range(of: "asd", options: .caseInsensitive)!.lowerBound)
```

but the separator is only inserted for the first occurrence of `"asd"`

Comment: What about instead replacing `"asd"` with  `"<*>" + "asd" + "<*>"` ? You can use `a = a.replacingOccurrences(of: "asd", with: "<*>$0<*>", options: [.caseInsensitive, .regularExpression])`?

Comment: @Larme This actually works, `$0` and `. regularExpression` did the magic, Thanks!

Comment: @Larme I think that you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Alladinian when there are already other questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52400793/how-to-replace-occurences-in-string-using-groups-in-swift https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61010309/regex-pattern-match-and-replace-in-swift etc. The good "idea" what to replace in a whole instead of twice, because the upperbounds/lowerbounds was more difficultt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: This solution was posted before OP mentioned a caseInsensitive requirement. A comment by Larme actually included such a solution:

```
replacingOccurrences(of: "asd", with: "<*>$0<*>", options: [.caseInsensitive, .regularExpression])
```

If he posts this as an answer feel free to accept it.

---

Here is a possible solution:

```
extension String {
    func enclosing(_ match: String, in tag: String) -> String {
        self.replacingOccurrences(of: match, with: tag + match + tag)
    }
}

let text = "asd as asdsd"
print(text.enclosing("asd", in: "<*>")) 
// Outputs: <*>asd<*> as <*>asd<*>sd
```

Comment: I thought about it, but the insertion should be caseInsensitive, so if the target is `"ASD"` the result should be the same:  `"<*>asd<*> as <*>asd<*>sd"`, but with this solution the result would be  `"<*>ASD<*> as <*>ASD<*>sd"`